# Hibernate @Generated(GenerationType.ALWAYS) is not populating my timestamps on update

Tags: java, hibernate

I have 2 timestamps on my entity, which are being populated by mySQL like so:

`created_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `last_modified_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

And I have annotated my entity fields like so:

```
@Column(name = "created_date", updatable=false, insertable=false)
@Generated(GenerationTime.INSERT)
Date createdDate;

@Column(name = "last_modified_date", updatable=false, insertable=false)
@Generated(GenerationTime.ALWAYS)
Date lastModifiedDate;
```

When I save a new entity, the entity fields are subsequently populated with the values that were populated by mySQL.

However, when I update my entity, the fields are subsequently null. Both createdDate and lastModifiedDate.

I have tried several other options:

1. I have included @Temporal annotations - no change
2. I have removed the updatable and insertable properties, removed the @Generated annotation, and used @PrePersist and @PreUpdate on a method which sets the dates in code - this results in null fields immediately after save and also immediately after update.
3. Immediately performing a "get" on my entity after insert/update - this obviously doesn't work because the entity is already in the session, so hibernate doesn't perform an actual DB query.

What I need is for both fields to be populated with a valid value immediately after save, and immediately after update.

This is the DAO/Repository code for update - all wrapped in a transaction at the service layer. I actually did not write this code, a junior developer did, and I see it needs refactoring, but I don't see anything that could cause what I'm seeing:

BaseHibernateDaoImpl:

```
protected HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate;

public void update(Object object) {
    hibernateTemplate.update(object);
}
```

UserCommentDaoImpl (extends BaseHibernateDaoImpl):

```
public void saveOrUpdate(UserComment userComment, UserAccount userAccount){
    UserComment existing  = getBy(userComment.getId(),userAccount,ActiveStatus.ACTIVE);
    if(existing != null) {
        evict(existing);
        update(userComment);
    } else {
        save(userComment);
    }
}
```

The same "saveOrUpdate" method is being used for create/save (which populates the timestamps) and update (which doesn't).

I am using:

- mySQL java connector version: 5.1.38
- Hibernate version: 5.1.0.Final
- Spring version: 4.2.5.RELEASE
- Java version: 1.8

Comment: What is the code updating the entity?

Comment: @JBNizet I added the relevent code you requested

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it was our non-recommended usage of hibernate that was the cause of the issue.

Our rest controller was building a new instance of UserComment from fields in a DTO. The timestamps were left null in this built instance. When our DAO "updated" the object, it was querying the persisted object from the DB, but then evicting that object and calling "hibernateSession.update" on  the instance that was built from the DTO (in other words, the instance was not in the session).

When I modified the code to keep the session instance, and copy the modified fields from the built instance, and then call "update" on the session instance, the timestamps began to populate just as I expected and needed them to.

Recommended hibernate usage decries (so I read) that update should never be called on an object that was not first loaded from the session. The persisted instance should be loaded, then modified, then updated.